# Program prints number of chars instead of words

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my program to print out the amount of words in a test string, but it's printing out a much larger number instead. For example, my test string has 24 words and my program prints out 102 instead. I'm wondering why it's doing that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char testval[1024]="This is a test... this is only a test... for the next sixty seconds this will be a test of the emergency broadcasting system.";

    int inWord=0;
    int wordCount=0;
    int i=0;
    while(testval[i] != 0) {
            if (testval[i]==' ') {
                    if (inWord) inWord=0;
            } else {
                    if (!inWord)
                            inWord=1;
                            wordCount++;
            }
            i++;
    }

    printf("The number of words in testval is %d\n",wordCount);
    return 0;
}


./numWords
The number of words in testval is 102
```

Comment: Have you traced your snippet with a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

```
                if (!inWord)
                        inWord=1;
                        wordCount++;
```

You missed a pair of `{}` to enclose the 2 statements. `wordCount++;` was executed for *all* non-space characters.

Answer (score 1):

For each space, just increment `wordCount`. Add one at the end and you have your answer.